# pipe from command run under different user Popen python3

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a Plex server on a raspberry pi and I have run into issues with getting the libraries to update so I was writing a python class that can be called to update all or specific libraries.

I would like to make it as general as possible, i.e., using library names instead of library numbers, but I am running into some issues. The "Plex Media Scanner" command must be run under the Plex user account in my current set up. I can get the command to run using the below code (run under sudo), but I cannot capture the output of the command, i.e., when the Popen part of the code runs, a list of the libraries prints to the terminal, however, the check_output command returns nothing. I have tried piping both stdout and stderr to subprocess.PIPE, but those do not capture anything either.

Running the code below gives me the following output

```
 15: Fitness
 10: Movies
  8: Music
  2: TV Shows
b''
```

with the first four lines being the output of Popen and the last the output of check_output. I have tested using a simple ['ls', '-l'] command with all other settings the same and check_output can capture the output. That tells me it must be just the Plex command. Has anyone had a similar issue with capturing output from a command and if so, how did you get around it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess as subp;
import pwd, os;

class plex_scan():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pw_record = pwd.getpwnam( 'plex' );
        self.env = os.environ.copy()
        self.env['HOME'           ] = self.pw_record.pw_dir
        self.env['PWD'            ] = self.pw_record.pw_dir
        self.env['LOGNAME'        ] = self.pw_record.pw_name
        self.env['USER'           ] = self.pw_record.pw_name
        self.env['PYTHONHOME'     ] = "/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Python";
        self.env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/plexmediaserver";

        cmd = ['/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Scanner', '--list']
        self.proc = subp.Popen(cmd, env=self.env); 
        self.proc.wait();
        out = subp.check_output(cmd, env=self.env); 
        print( out );
if __name__ == "__main__":
  x = plex_scan( );   
  exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out a solution to this problem. The issue was that the Plex Media Scanner program was writing to the 4kb buffer and the subprocess.PIPE was not catching it.

I added

```
stdbuf -oL -eL
```

to the begging of the command to be run, making the new command

```
cmd = ['stdbuf', '-oL', '-eL', '/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Scanner', '--list']
```

and this did the trick. See also:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1dmhsz/subprocesspopen_stdout_flush_the_buffer/#bottom-comments

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe